# Nested with clause in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use nested `with`:

```
CREATE TABLE audit_trail (
      old_email TEXT NOT NULL,
      new_email TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO audit_trail(old_email, new_email)
  VALUES ('harold_gim@yahoo.com', 'hgimenez@hotmail.com'),
         ('hgimenez@hotmail.com', 'harold.gimenez@gmail.com'),
         ('harold.gimenez@gmail.com', 'harold@heroku.com'),
         ('foo@bar.com', 'bar@baz.com'),
         ('bar@baz.com', 'barbaz@gmail.com');

with iter2 as (
    with iter1 as (
        select old_email, new_email from audit_trail where old_email = 'harold_gim@yahoo.com'
        ) select a.old_email, a.new_email from audit_trail a join iter1 b on (a.old_email = b.new_email)
) select * from iter1 union iter2;
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "iter2" at character 264
STATEMENT:  with iter2 as (
        with iter1 as (
            select old_email, new_email from audit_trail where old_email = 'harold_gim@yahoo.com'
            ) select a.old_email, a.new_email from audit_trail a join iter1 b on (a.old_email = b.new_email)
    ) select * from iter1 union iter2;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "iter2"
LINE 5: ) select * from iter1 union iter2;
```

Syntax error, obviously. Is nested with supported?

PostgreSQL version 9.4.4

Answer (score 15):

The error message concerns inproper `union` syntax, it should be

```
...
select * from iter1 
union 
select * from iter2;
```

In this case however you will get the error

```
ERROR:  relation "iter1" does not exist
LINE 6: select * from iter1
```

because nested `with` statement can be used but the table defined in an inner query is not visible outside the outer query. Use list of queries:

```
with iter1 as (
    select old_email, new_email 
    from audit_trail 
    where old_email = 'harold_gim@yahoo.com'
    ),
iter2 as (
    select a.old_email, a.new_email 
    from audit_trail a 
    join iter1 b on (a.old_email = b.new_email)
    )
select * from iter1 
union 
select * from iter2;
```